# Active Admin: sorting on multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Active Admin doesn't seem to support multiple columns sorting yet (i.e. pass multiple values to the `config.sortable` option).
I saw an old monkey patch [here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1766#issuecomment-10450799) but it doesn't seem to work with my version (1.0.0.pre from Github).

Is there any way to get multiple sortable columns on the latest Active Admin version?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is also a monkey patch:

Create a new file in config/initializers or in the lib folder: `multiple_columns_sorting.rb`

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController < BaseController
    module DataAccess
      def apply_sorting(chain)
        params[:order] ||= active_admin_config.sort_order

        orders = []
        params[:order].split('_and_').each do |fragment|
          order_clause = OrderClause.new fragment
          if order_clause.valid?
            orders << order_clause.to_sql(active_admin_config)
          end
        end

        if orders.empty?
          chain
        else
          chain.reorder(orders.shift).order(orders)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Restart the server. Now you can use several columns name separeted by `"_and_"`. For example:

```
config.sort_order = 'first_name_desc_and_last_name_asc'
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to award the bounty.

Comment: Thanks, Bastien Léonard. :)

Answer (score 6):

For ActiveAdmin v0.6.0, I tweaked the monkey patch to something like this

```
# initializers/active_admin.rb
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController
    module DataAccess
      def apply_sorting(chain)
        params[:order] ||= active_admin_config.sort_order

        orders = []
        params[:order].present? && params[:order].split(/\s*,\s*/).each do |fragment|
          fragment =~ /^([\w\_\.]+)_(desc|asc)$/
          column = $1
          order  = $2
          table  = active_admin_config.resource_column_names.include?(column) ? active_admin_config.resource_table_name : nil
          table_column = (column =~ /\./) ? column :
            [table, active_admin_config.resource_quoted_column_name(column)].compact.join(".")

          orders << "#{table_column} #{order}"
        end

        if orders.empty?
          chain
        else
          chain.reorder(orders.shift).order(orders)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For my case, I would use it as following as it's more natural to me:

```
config.sort_order = 'first_name_desc, last_name_asc'
```

The details are from my gist https://gist.github.com/anhkind/5e9d849ebe4f3a452e31

Answer (score 4):

You can add something like this

```
ActiveAdmin.register Model do
  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Model.order('field_1 DESC, field2 ASC')
    end
  end

  config.sort_order = ''
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The patch didn't work with the latest version.  Two minor changes below.  Works with v2.8.1

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class ResourceController < BaseController
    module DataAccess
      def apply_sorting(chain)
        params[:order] ||= active_admin_config.sort_order

        orders = []
        params[:order].split('_and_').each do |fragment|
          order_clause = OrderClause.new(active_admin_config, fragment)
          if order_clause.valid?
            orders << order_clause.to_sql
          end
        end

        if orders.empty?
          chain
        else
          chain.reorder(orders.shift).order(orders)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if its just 1 or 2 fields you want to update, then you can do it like this. In your Active Admin Controller just use this method. This method over uses first_name and last_name column for sorting, when you pass full_name for sorting.

```
def apply_sorting(chain)
      params[:order] ||= active_admin_config.sort_order
      order_clause = ActiveAdmin::OrderClause.new params[:order]

  if order_clause.field == 'full_name'
      chain.reorder("(first_name, last_name)  #{order_clause.order}")
  else
      super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently a new method `order_by` was added:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Resource do
  config.sort_order = 'field_foo_desc'

  order_by(:field_foo) do |order_clause|
    fields = [:field_foo, :field_bar]

    fields.map { |field|
      Resource.arel_table[field].public_send(order_clause.order)
    }.map(&:to_sql).join(', ')
  end
end
```

See **Custom sorting** here https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html

See also `ActiveAdmin::OrderClause#custom_sql`