# active_admin config.sort for two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I have an active_admin table called `shows` that acts of a list of rsvps for bike riders and bike shows that the riders will compete in.  The following code correctly sorts the table alphabetically by `rider_last_name`:

```
config.sort_order = 'rider_last_name_asc'
```

Now when a rider is attending multiple bike shows, I want the table to first sort by rider_last_name and then within that rider sort by an attribute of `shows` called `start_time`.  `start_time` is a DateTime.  According to [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212983/rails-active-admin-how-to-config-sort-order-with-2-columns-1-column-from-associ), the following should work:

```
config.sort_order = 'rider_last_name_asc, start_time_asc'
```

but it doesn't.  In fact, it undoes the sorting by `rider_last_name`.  How do I sort by both columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ActiveAdmin** [suggests](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L50) overwrite the `find_collection` method, which returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. But I prefer add the `order` to it's output.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Show do

  controller do
    def find_collection(options = {})
      super.reorder(rider_last_name: :asc, start_time: :asc)
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Although it works, this overwrite the user option of click on a column.

**Alternative**

You can do the same with `scoped_collection`, which is called at the start of `find_collection`, but it does not work unless you add `active_admin_config.sort_order = ''` to the controller. This way:

```
controller do
  active_admin_config.sort_order = ''
  def scoped_collection
    super.reorder(rider_last_name: :asc, start_time: :asc)
  end
end
```

Now, if we want to reorder before and, after that take care of the user params (and do not overwrite them). This is the way.

*Note*: I did use `active_admin_config.sort_order` and not `config.sort_order`.

Also, the `sort_order` option, ends as a param of `OrderClause.new` call, which expect for only one sort field, see [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L216) and [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/order_clause.rb#L5).

Comment: @Philip7899 Did you try any of these options, because I did and both works for me. Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You may try refine **apply_sorting** method for collections, like this:

```
controller do
  def apply_sorting(chain)
    params[:order] ? chain : chain.reorder(rider_last_name: :asc, start_time: :asc)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to pass an array to it as such:

```
config.sort_order = [:rider_last_name_asc, :start_time_asc]
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but it does not work.  It just undoes any ordering and does active_Admin's default order by id.

Comment: so looking at OrderSort of ActiveAdmin it doesnt look like they support it any longer, however a monkey patch described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672758/active-admin-sorting-on-multiple-columns should work for you